# shell script to execute command2 after completion of command1 in unix

Tags: shell, serial-processing

If I have a UNIX shell script which has some commands on each line that needs to be run, like

```
#!/bin/bash
command1
command2
```

command2 to be excuted only after completion of command1. how to achieve it

Answer (score 2):

You've already done it.  bash normally waits for each command to run before running the next command.  If you end the command with an ampersand (`&`), then it runs the command in the background, but since you haven't done that, each command runs synchronously.